# ME State in Recovery Mode

Tags: motherboard

I have a HP Elitebook Folio that when it boots for a few seconds at POST it displays on the screen, in the upper left hand corner, in red letters on a white background the message "ME State in Recovery Mode". The message displays along with the HP logo for a few seconds and then the system boots normally into Windows.  Everything runs normally and without issue.

This is apparently related to the Intel Management Engine.  HP recommends updating to the current version which I have with no change.  Everything appears to update and install without issue.  No error messages. Nothing in the event logs that I can see (Windows 7 Pro x64).

Has anyone seen this before?  Any suggestions on how to go about making the alert go away?

Answer (score 2):

Intel AMT firmware is faulty or its version is different from main BIOS firmware version.
This may happen due to BIOS upgrade or motherboard replacement.
Several things may help:

1. You can try resetting the CMOS by removing the back cover of the laptop. You'll see a small battery - pick it off and plug in it back in some time.  "IF", and it's a big if, this works upon reboot the system should take you to the MEBx setup page or give you an option to go into the BIOS. Press the keys Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot. When the logo appears press Ctrl+P. You should now be looking at the MEBx menu. Set the Default values. Click OK. Reboot.
2. You can also try reinstalling device drivers if you also see a yellow exclamation mark next to  "Intel (R) Active Management Technology" in Device Manager. This error will almost surely accompany the "ME is in recovery state" error. It sometimes helps but not often.
3. Downgrade/Upgrade your BIOS
   Install several older BIOS versions that would match AMT one after another.
   When reinstalling the AMT firmware and it took 3 or 4 minutes and looked like it had hung at 100% for a while. Don't interrupted it, it's still working, just let it finish. Sometimes vice versa, flashing the newest version  helps.

After finishing with the update then you can patch Intel Full ME 8 Firmware Component.
Here is ME FW for HP EliteBook Folio 9470m: http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/kb/search?sp4ts.oid=5271995&ac.admitted=1449062706385.1123376534.199480143

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response.  I'll give these a try and see what we get.